# SQL Server 2005 Export table to csv file splitting records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using export wizard in tasks to export address table rows to CSV file. The table hold 100k records but some rows are split onto the next row. The split occurs on the street column.

i.e `23 wood lane london SW1 7Ab` would result in export of two rows:

```
23 wood
lane lane london SW1 7Ab
```

This would only happen on a few hundred rows. Have tried replace with SQL query replace to remove hidden special characters. I have used the quote and pipe separator.

Any ideas what else to try?

Comment: Are you certain there aren't any special characters (such as a line break) in this field?  It seems very odd that it would randomly insert a line break for a few hundred records out of 100,000.

Comment: try replacing char(10), char(13) and others as @Siyual mentioned ont his column... something like `replace(replace(addressColumn,char(10),' '),char(13),' ')`. Or, at least show what you have tried specifically when you say *Have tried with SQL query replace to remove hidden special characters*

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Thanks scsimon\siyual. The database does gets updates from various sources so it may well contain special characters. will give replace another go

Comment: I'd copy and paste the SQL query result of that column into an editor like Notepad++ or something to display special characters.

Comment: Thanks keith will give that a go tomorrow